# error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, font-awesome

I am trying to use Font-awesome icons in my Angular-13 Application, whenever I try to use `<fa-icon [icon]="[someIconName]"></fa-icon>` it throws a below errors. I am unable to use any of the font-awesome Icons. Please help me with this. I further deleted `node_module` folder and then reinstalled it but was unable to fix it.

> ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoE6b.png).rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoE6b.png)!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoE6b.png).rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>
> - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js): Warning
>
> (6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust.
> The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
>
> ./node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/fesm2015/angular-fontawesome.mjs
>
> - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>   TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string
>   'C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules@fortawesome\angular-fontawesome\fesm2015\angular-fontawesome.mjs:
>   This application depends upon a library published using Angular
>   version 14.0.0, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work
>   correctly. Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent
>   version of Angular.   134 | }   135 | FaStackItemSizeDirective.ɵfac =
>   i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "14.0.0",
>   ngImport: i0, type: FaStackItemSizeDirective, deps: [], target:
>   i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Directive });
>
> > 136 | FaStackItemSizeDirective.ɵdir = i0.ɵɵngDeclareDirective({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "14.0.0", type:
> > FaStackItemSizeDirective,  selector:
> > "fa-icon[stackItemSize],fa-duotone-icon[stackItemSize]", inputs: {
> > stackItemSize: "stackItemSize", size: "size" }, usesOnChanges: true,
> > ngImport: i0 });
> > |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^9m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^9m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^9m^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > 137 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version:
> > "14.0.0", ngImport: i0, type: FaStackItemSizeDirective, decorators: [{
> > 138 |             type: Directive,   139 |             args: [{'
> > at run (C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:37:15)
> > at run.next ()
> > at Function.transform (C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:41)
> > at transform.next ()
> > at step (C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
> > at C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
> > at async.call.result.err.err (C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
> > at C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules\gensync\index.js:37:40
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/icon/duotone-icon.component.d.ts:54:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).
>
> 54     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FaDuotoneIconComponent,
> "fa-duotone-icon", never, { "swapOpacity": "swapOpacity";
> "primaryOpacity": "primaryOpacity"; "secondaryOpacity":
> "secondaryOpacity"; "primaryColor": "primaryColor"; "secondaryColor":
> "secondaryColor"; }, {}, never, never, false>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/icon/icon.component.d.ts:66:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).
>
> 66     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FaIconComponent,
> "fa-icon", never, { "icon": "icon"; "title": "title"; "spin": "spin";
> "pulse": "pulse"; "mask": "mask"; "styles": "styles"; "flip": "flip";
> "size": "size"; "pull": "pull"; "border": "border"; "inverse":
> "inverse"; "symbol": "symbol"; "rotate": "rotate"; "fixedWidth":
> "fixedWidth"; "classes": "classes"; "transform": "transform";
> "a11yRole": "a11yRole";  }, {}, never, never, false>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/layers/layers-counter.component.d.ts:20:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).
>
> 20     static ɵcmp:
> i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FaLayersCounterComponent,
> "fa-layers-counter", never, { "content": "content"; "title": "title";
> "styles": "styles"; "classes": "classes"; "position": "position"; },
> {}, never, never, false>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/layers/layers-text.component.d.ts:32:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).
>
> 32     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FaLayersTextComponent,
> "fa-layers-text", never, { "content": "content"; "title": "title";
> "styles": "styles"; "classes": "classes"; "spin": "spin"; "pulse":
> "pulse"; "flip": "flip"; "size": "size"; "pull": "pull"; "border":
> "border"; "inverse": "inverse"; "rotate": "rotate"; "fixedWidth":
> "fixedWidth"; "transform": "transform"; }, {}, never, never, false>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/layers/layers.component.d.ts:18:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).
>
> 18     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FaLayersComponent,
> "fa-layers", never, { "size": "size"; "fixedWidth": "fixedWidth"; },
> {}, never, ["*"], false>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/stack/stack-item-size.directive.d.ts:11:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires 6 type argument(s).
>
> 11     static ɵdir:
> i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<FaStackItemSizeDirective,
> "fa-icon[stackItemSize],fa-duotone-icon[stackItemSize]", never, {
> "stackItemSize": "stackItemSize"; "size": "size"; }, {}, never, never,
> false>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error:
> node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/stack/stack.component.d.ts:18:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).
>
> 18     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FaStackComponent,
> "fa-stack", never, { "size": "size"; }, {}, never, ["*"], false>;

This is `package.json`
[image]

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Hi @rakesh-gombi, please share your package.json file into a code snippet to help you better, please check why this is important. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9676887)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is quite hard to guess the error without more information, but following the error message:

`TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\ALTrakesg2\Downloads\Employee-feedback-management-system\frontend\node_modules\@fortawesome\angular-fontawesome\fesm2015\angular-fontawesome.mjs:` **This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.0.0, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.**

Looks like you need to upgrade `Angular` version in order to use your current `@fontawesome` library version.

Comment: I had a similar problem with ng-recaptcha. To fix it, I just downloaded ng-recaptcha v9, which is compatible with Angular 13.

Comment: Any way to dongrate the version back to what I had before ?  It all started once I upgradete to angular 14 , That I don't really need anyway .

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Angular version, you should install the matching @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome version, to do this, just check the compatibility table:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome
Example for Angular 14.x:

```
npm i -S @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.11.0  @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Answer (score 2):

Update Your ngx-toastr version that is compatable with angular and type script version...

in my case when i install the ngx-toaster with command:-> npm install ngx-toastr

the latest version of toastr installed which is 16.1.1 so i am getting this error
:

```
node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-noanimation.component.d.ts:50:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

50     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ToastNoAnimation, "[toast-component]", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>;
                    
Error: node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast.component.d.ts:57:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

57     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<Toast<any>, "[toast-component]", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>;
                    
Error: node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast.directive.d.ts:8:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

8     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<ToastContainerDirective, "[toastContainer]", ["toastContainer"], {}, {}, never, never, false, never>;
```

For Solution: I uninstall the version of ngx-toastr using command :-> npm uninstall ngx-toastr

Then Reinstall ngx-toastr version compatable with my configuration of the angular and typescirpt versions using the command: npm install ngx-toastr@15.2.2 --save in my case the version 15.2.2 is working maybe your case the version number differ's

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer @Sahil Chauhan. As I'm learning Angular without other's support, I'm spending lot of time even to resolve small error. Your answer has resolved my issue. I could able to resolve ngx-bootstrap issue.

Comment: Your's welcome @Ashokkumar

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 13, use :

```
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.10.x
```

It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything ,just match your angular version with fontawesome version and then,it's ready to use....
Go through this link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `@angular/material`, and reinstall from with the official command which makes a previous configuration of the theme to use, the error occurs due to unmatchability or not selecting a default theme.

Solution: install angular-core version.

```
npm install @angular/cdk@version
ng add @angular/material@version
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with toastr in Angular.

Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

```
50     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ToastNoAnimation, "[toast-component]", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>
```

Just change your config to

```
ToastrModule.forRoot(
      {
        maxOpened: 1,
        progressBar: true,
        progressAnimation: 'decreasing',
        preventDuplicates: true,
      }),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install ng-apexcharts@1.7.1
```

resolved the problem in my case.